# Is there a way to Out-Null $PSinstance.BeginInvoke() for Runspaces?

Tags: powershell, runspace

I tried:

```
$PSinstance.BeginInvoke() | Out-Null
```

but when I do this it waits for the enter key to be pressed to continue. This is weird because without the out-null it continues fine. I also tried assigning it to a variable and it behaves the same way. If I write-host after that line it also continue but I don't want any output

```
param(
[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
$Location,

[Parameter(Mandatory = $true
)]
$Logs,

[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
$date
)

$InitialSessionState = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState]::CreateDefault()

foreach ($Parameter in $PSBoundParameters.Keys) {
    $Variable = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateVariableEntry]::new($Parameter, $PSBoundParameters[$Parameter], $Null)
    $InitialSessionState.Variables.Add($Variable)
}

$RunspacePool = [runspacefactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1,[int]$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS+1, $InitialSessionState, $Host)
$RunspacePool.ApartmentState = "STA"
$RunspacePool.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
$RunspacePool.Open()


$PSinstance = [powershell]::Create().AddScript({

   Write-Host "$Location $Logs $date"

})
$PSinstance.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
$PSinstance.BeginInvoke() | Out-Null
$PSinstance.Streams.Information
```

Comment: Could you create a [mcve] for this? I would like to try some things out for it but I don't have much occasion to use `.BeginInvoke()` myself.

Comment: Just added some sample code. $PSinstance.Streams.Information is the only output that I want

Comment: @mklement0 I'm on also on  5.1 and $null= did not work

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. At the bottom you can do this to get around the hang:

```
$PSinstance.RunspacePool = $RunspacePool
$PSinstance.BeginInvoke() | Out-Null 
Write-Host "$($PSinstance.Streams.Information)"
```

Comment: Did you perhaps simply mean to use [`.Invoke()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.invoke?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0), the _synchronous_ invocation method rather than the asynchronous `.BeginInvoke()` method?